# Dynamically create custom fields

Tags: apex, custom-field, metadata-api

I am looking for a way to create custom field from Apex.

Use case: we are using a specific field (E.g.: `Own_Id_Field__c, TEXT(255), ExternalID: TRUE`).

User should be able to select which (Custom) Object they want to use in the app and this should create custom field (for good functioning).

I would like to do someting like:

```
public static Schema.DescribeFieldResult createOwnIdField(String sObject) {
  // Test if sObject exists
  // Create field
  return field;
}
```

I heard about using Metadata API but did not really understood.

Comment: @RahulSharma Thanks. I would like confirmation of compatibility with 41

Comment: Its relatively easy, what's stopping you to try and confirm it? The [Metadata API wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/tree/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes) by [Andrew Fawcett](https://twitter.com/andyinthecloud) really works well, there should be no reason for it to break in version `41`, that is being used by a lot of ISV's as well.